# Terminal Crashing

Tags: macos, terminal

I was trying to install ruby on my Mac and i just opened terminal and it won't let me type anything in it, when i go to open it 2 windows pop up both with the same message on.

```
[forkpty: Resource temporarily unavailable]
[Could not create a new process and open a pseudo-tty.]
```

I don't really know what it means and i have never come across this problem before, i tried quitting terminal and restarting my Mac but it just does the same thing.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try logging in as a different user, using `sudo bash` to get an administrative shell and then go to your normal user directory and undo the changes you made to your login/profile script.

Comment: Sorry, how do you mean go to my normal user director and undo the changes I made? I don't think I changed any login scripts or anything.

Comment: I suspect an installation script has changed your login script.

Comment: Any way of finding out if any has? Because I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed this problem! I tried logging into guest user and then going back into my current user and it seems to have been fixed.